# Catching an error within a method that has a boolean return type

Tags: java

I am attempting to implement a game of Hex, using some interfaces i've been given. Part of the implementation is notifying the user and the program that a player has attempted to place a piece upon a board co-ordinate (A 2D array list) that already contains a piece. This is deemed an illegal move. Therefore, I am attempting to catch the exception within my placePiece() method which assigns a piece to some given co-ordinates. Piece is an enumerated class which contains three elements: BLUE, RED, UNSET. Initially I set the board to UNSET. I need the method to notify the user and the system of a PositionAlreadyTakenException should the co-ordinates contain anything other Piece.UNSET. Can anyone help me do this as at the moment the method is just skipping to the last return true; line of code?

Here is the code for my makeMove() method:

```
 public boolean placePiece(Piece colour, MoveInterface move) throws PositionAlreadyTakenException, InvalidPositionException, InvalidColourException
{
       int x = move.getXPosition();
       int y = move.getYPosition(); 

       try {
        if(this.board [y-1][x-1] == Piece.UNSET){
         this.board[y-1][x -1] = colour;  
         return true; 
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        return false; 
    }    
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: so instead of a `try catch` you want to have and `if else` Saying this `if(this.board[......] blah) { do stuff return true;} else { throws PositionAlreadyTakenException;}`

Answer (score 0):

i think you're looking for something like this

```
public boolean placePiece(Piece colour, MoveInterface move) throws PositionAlreadyTakenException, InvalidPositionException, InvalidColourException
{
       int x = move.getXPosition();
       int y = move.getYPosition(); 

       try {
        if(this.board [y-1][x-1] == Piece.UNSET){
         this.board[y-1][x -1] = colour;  
         return true; 
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        SOPL ("error" + e.getMessage(); 
    }    
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: What means `SOPL`?

Comment: system out println, sorry bad habits

Answer (score 0):

Try `catch (Throwable t)` instead.

But it's still bad style. An exception should only be thrown in exceptional situations. An already claimed place is application logic.